# How to set a position to Ext.Msg.show in sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can I set a different position for Ext.Msg.show in senchatouch. I have tried using the methods

```
msg.getDialog().getPositionEl().setTop(50);
```

&

```
msg.getDialog().setPosition(undefined,50)
```

However I am getting a error `Object [object Object] has no method 'getPositionEl'` or `Object [object Object] has no method 'getDialog'`.

I have even checked these methods in my MessageBox.js file in sencha but they do not exist.

However almost solution on the net seems to recommend these methods.Experts could you kindly advise.

Comment: Please can anyone suggest a solution ?

Comment: I too have the same problem, did you resolve this somehow?
Can you please share some knowledge of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can place messagebox to certain position by specifying `left` and `top` config options.

```
launch: function() {
    var msg = Ext.Msg.show({
            title:'Some title',
            message:'Sample message container.',
            left:50, // mention initial positioning with left and top config.
            top:50,
            buttons:[{  //create as many buttons you want. 
                text:'Ok',
                ui:'action',
                handler:function(btn){
                    if(msg.getTop() == 200) // Just for demo. Click Ok and place msg box to some other position. If clicked again, hide message box
                        msg.hide();
                    else{
                        msg.setTop(200); 
                        msg.setLeft(200);
                    }
                }
            }]
    });
}
```

Other than config options, you can align message box with `setTop()` and `setLeft()` methods as well.

See [Demo](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#A2pAR). As you can see, message box is not placed at center as it's default position is center but instead it is placed with top and left set to 50.

Comment: It's always better not to use inline CSS and put the CSS in a file and use the cls config with Sencha