# Positioning of Ext.msg.show() - Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to position my msg Box but in vain.
The following is my code for the box:

```
var msg = Ext.Msg.show({     
 msg:'<br><br>'+'Enter Valid Quatity',
 buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
 modal: false,
 animEl: 'mb9',
 cls: 'msgbox',
 fn: function(btn){
  if(btn == 'ok'){   
  myMasks.hide();
  }
 }
});
```

css hack:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .msgbox{
  left: 257px!important;
  top: 266px!important;
  width: 250px;
  height: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px!important;
 }
 .x-css-shadow{
 display:none !important;
 }
</style>
```

When I hack the css to position the box, the shadow is visible. I hid this shadow in Mozilla again using css but unable to do the same in IE.

Also I followed the answer given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879410/how-to-set-a-position-to-ext-msg-show-in-sencha) with no use.

Can anyone please provide me a solution to either position the box directly using the config properties of Extjs or hide the shadow of the box in IE successfully?

Comment: Is there a reason for tagging Java and JSP?

Comment: Sometimes people think that I have used PHP and reply in relation to that. To avoid that I tagged those two

Comment: Freakyuser, where is the code you are currently using to position your MsgBox?

Comment: this may help you http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?92735-How-can-I-set-the-position-of-a-MessageBox-window

Comment: I have also created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cd9) to show that I am unable to position the mask message box properly in my panel

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you can remove the `animEl` config as this is not valid for ExtJS 4 and 5.
And use the setXY() method to place the MessageBox whereever you want:

```
var msg = Ext.Msg.show({     
    msg:'<br><br>'+'Enter Valid Quatity',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
   //modal: false, */ No need for this because modal defaults to false */
   fn: function(btn){
       if(btn == 'ok'){   
           myMasks.hide();
       }
   }
});
Ext.Msg.setXY([257,266],false); // You can set the second argument to another object if you want the box to animate from it.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried giving `Ext.Msg.setXY([25,26], false);` but the box stayed in the same position.

Comment: Can you try creating a fiddle with your problem? After I applied the setXY method, the msgBox got positioned correctly.

Comment: I have also created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cd9) to show that I am unable to position the mask message box properly in my panel

Comment: Hey Freakyuser, I've made some changes to your fiddle and saved it here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cdb. I'm displaying the box at [0,0]